# C - Searching for the syscall table in 64-bit Linux kernel using brute force

Tags: c, linux-kernel, 64-bit, system-calls, brute-force

I am not very familiar with C programming and I'm trying to find the start and end addresses of the syscall table in Linux 64-bit. I tried the solution described in the link below:
https://memset.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/syscall-hijacking-dynamically-obtain-syscall-table-address-kernel-2-6-x-2/

But it is designed for a 32-bit kernel so there are some incompatibilities that cause errors and stop the make of the makefile. I'm currently getting this error:

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
         printk("Syscall table found at %x\n", (unsigned ) syscall_table);
                                               ^ cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

which might be because the start and end addresses of in a 64-bit kernel are different than the ones specified for the 32-bit but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's so confusing about that? The warning very clearly states the problem: You're casting a 64-bit pointer to a 32-bit `unsigned`.
You could either:
Instead cast to `unsigned long long`, which would get rid of the immediate problem, or:
Do the right thing, and use the `%p` specifier in the `printk()` (I assume printk() understands `%p`?), and cast the pointer to `void*`.

Comment: I tried both ways, the first didn't work and gave a "format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long unsigned int’" but the second fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @SalmaFG: For completeness: If you cast to `unsigned long long`, you also need to modify the `printk()`-specifier to `%llx`